# Windows-8 FlipView issue with touch?

Tags: windows-8

I am running Windows 8 Consumer Preview and having an issue with the FlipView control.
In the Windows 8 SDK Sample pack (for Consumer Preview), there is a Controls_FlipView project that shows different things that can be done with the FlipView control. If I run the project in the Simulator and use the touch pointer (hand) and try flipping through the slides, if I flip relatively quickly, the FlipView sometimes ends the animation in between two slides, after letting go of the mouse. This also happens in a FlipView control in my own app.

screenshot: http://i39.tinypic.com/noa3o2.png

Is this a quirk/bug of the simulator? Or does this also happen on a real tablet? (I don't have one to check)

Comment: Hi,
Never seen this bug before but I suggest you to migrate from Consumer Preview to the Release Preview which has been shipped 3 weeks ago. There is a lot of changes between the two versions and therefore you'll have to do some consequent modification to your application. I guess if it's a bug they certainly have fixed it